# Add command to lauch a new application from terminal

Tags: unity, 13.04, command-line

I've installed BlueGriffon on Ubuntu 13.04 x64bit. I've add it to Unity Launcher by creating a "bluegriffon.desktop" file. Now I want to launch bluegriffon directly from terminal; assuming that the prgram folder is on the path `/home/username/programs/bluegriffon` and assuming that the laucher's file name is `bluegriffon`, which code I have to add to `.bashrc` and `.profile`?

Note: I tried to add PATH to `.profile`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can add symbolic link to `/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` for executable file. For example:

```
ln -s /home/username/programs/bluegriffon/EXECUTABLE.sh /usr/local/bin/bluegriffon
```

Answer (score 1):

To launch it from the terminal by entering its name only (in this case 'bluergriffon') you will need the program's folder in your path. The path is set using the PATH environment variable and you can add the following to .profile to set it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/programs/bluegriffon
```

This appends the new folder to the existing value of the PATH variable so you don't lose the existing contents.

The 'export' command makes the value of the environment variable available to subprocesses.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Remember the quotes around `$PATH`! :-)